# Elasticsearch: Job for elasticsearch.service failed

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently trying to setup **Elasticsearch** for a project. I have installed `Elasticsearch 7.4.1` and I have also installed **Java**, that is `openjdk 11.0.4`.

But when I try to start **Elasticsearch** using the command

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

I get the error below

> Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

> See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

And when I try to run the command

```
systemctl status elasticsearch.service
```

I get the error message

> ● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch

> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vend

> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-11-01 06:09:54 UTC; 12s ago

> ```
> Docs: http://www.elastic.co
> ```

> Process: 5960 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DI

> Main PID: 5960 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

I have removed/purged **Elasticsearch** from my machine and re-installed several times, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

I have tried to modify the default `network.host` and `host.port` settings in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` to `network.host: 0.0.0.0` and `http.port: 9200` to fix the issue, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**Here's how I solved**

Firstly, Open `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` in your nano editor using the command below:

```
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

Your network settings should be:

```
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 127.0.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
```

In order for **Elasticsearch** to allow connections from localhost, and to also listen on port `9200`.

Next, run the code below to determine the cause of the error:

```
journalctl -xe
```

**Error 1**

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

**Solution**

As a JVM application, the **Elasticsearch** main server process only utilizes memory devoted to the JVM. The required memory may depend on the JVM used (32- or 64-bit). The memory used by JVM usually consists of:

- **heap space** (configured via `-Xms` and `-Xmx`)
- **metaspace** (limited by the amount of available native memory)
- **internal JVM** (usually tens of Mb)
- OS-dependent memory features like **memory-mapped files**.

Elasticsearch mostly depends on the **heap memory**, and this setting manually by passing the `-Xms` and `-Xmx`(heap space) option to the JVM running the **Elasticsearch** server.

**Solution**

Open `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` in your nano editor using the command below:

```
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
```

First, un-comment the value of `Xmx` and `Xms`

Next, modify the value of `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to no more than 50% of your physical RAM. The value for these settings depends on the amount of RAM available on your server and Elasticsearch requires memory for purposes other than the JVM heap and it is important to leave space for this.

**Minimum requirements**: If your physical RAM is **<= 1 GB**

Then, your settings should be:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms128m
-Xmx128m
```

OR

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms256m
-Xmx256m
```

**Medium requirements**: If your physical RAM is **>= 2 GB** but **<= 4 GB**

Then, your settings should be:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

OR

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms750m
-Xmx750m
```

**Large requirements**: If your physical RAM is **>= 4 GB** but **<= 8 GB**

Then, your settings should be:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```

OR

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
```

**Note**: If your physical RAM is **>= 8 GB** you can decide how much heap space you want to allocate to Elasticsearch. You can allocate `-Xms2048m` and `-Xmx2048m` OR `-Xms4g` and `-Xmx4g` or even higher for better performance based on your available resources.

**Error 2**

> Initial heap size not equal to the maximum heap size

**Solution**

Ensure the value of `-Xms` and `Xmx` are equal. That is, say, you are using the **minimum requirements** since your physical RAM is **<= 1 GB**, instead of this:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms128m
-Xmx256m
```

it should be this:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms128m
-Xmx128m
```

OR this:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms256m
-Xmx256m
```

**Error 3**

> the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured

**Solution**

Open `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` in your nano editor using the command below:

```
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

Your discovery settings should be:

```
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: []
```

Once all the errors are fixed run the command below to start and confirm the status of **Elasticsearch**:

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

That's all.

Comment: If you are using a $5 digital ocean (RAM: 1go) droplet like me, it is recommended to set `-Xms512mo` and `-Xmx512mo`.

Comment: That would be about 50% of your RAM @JulienLeCoupanec, which I don't think is advisable. I will advise that you should rather consider -Xmx128m.

Comment: @PromisePreston, you are right, I had to switch back to 128mo. It caused a lot of trouble when running another script on the side.

Comment: changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 and uncomment http.port 9200 work for me.

Comment: I had "Out of memory" errors when starting ES. In `jvm.options`, `-Xms4g` and `-Xmx4g` worked for me. Ubuntu 20.04, 32g ram.

Comment: I never had "discovery.seed_hosts: []" in my file originally but then added it. Taking it out seemed to have fixed some issue for me

Answer (score 14):

A basic solution to this problem is to just uninstall Elasticsearch and Kibana and again re-install them and your problem will be solved.

For uninstalling Elasticsearch:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge elasticsearch
```

The message was:

> dpkg: warning: while removing elasticsearch, directory '/var/lib/elasticsearch' not empty so not removed
> dpkg: warning: while removing elasticsearch, directory '/etc/elasticsearch' not empty so not removed

Removed those directories as well:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/elasticsearch
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

Then install it again:

```
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch=7.10.1
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
curl http://localhost:9200/
```

For uninstalling Kibana:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge kibana
```

Removed those directories as well:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/kibana
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/kibana
```

Then install it again:

```
sudo apt-get install kibana=7.10.1
sudo systemctl start kibana
```

For opening Kibana on browser:

```
http://localhost:5601
```

Comment: good to know :)

Answer (score 12):

Had the same problem with a small virtual machine. The above configurations were already set. The only thing that helped was to increase the start timeout. The standard systemd timeout was just not enough.

As a precaution, I set the timeout to 5 minutes as follows.

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service
```

Added under [Service] section in elasticsearch.service file.

```
TimeoutStartSec=300
```

Activate change to service.

```
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
```

Start service again.

```
service elasticsearch start
```

Comment: note that the "TimeoutStartSec" is at the end of the file, don't add a new one. Short helpful article here: https://terryl.in/en/elasticsearch-service-start-operation-timed-out/

Comment: this was helpful with my ELK(Elastic 8.6.2), plus i also increase value of -Xms and Xmx

Answer (score 8):

If you installed using package management, check if the owner of `/etc/elasticsearch` directory is elasticsearch.

```
sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /etc/elasticsearch/
```

Comment: Worked for me too. I did all of the above in the approved answer, but this made it run!

Answer (score 3):

First verify that this is the same problem with command:

```
journalctl -xe
```

If you see error like this **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class**
then do this:

My solution I got from here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/57018

```
sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
```

Add this at the end or beggining of the file

```
# Elasticsearch temp directory
ES_TMPDIR=/var/log/elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try a system restart or just logging-out**

I had the same issue as OP on a fresh install of ES. Before going down a rabbit hole of logs and Google searches, I simply tried logging-out of my OS (Ubuntu 20.04) and logged back in. Opened a fresh terminal and elasticsearch was able to start successfully.

For reference, I used:

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

and checked it with:

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

Comment: Although this may work (starting a fresh boot), on a longer subsequent session I encountered memory errors yet again. So rather than always reboot, instead I used the  `jvm.options` fix as [Promise Preston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656748/4378314) suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to install elasticsearch 7.15.2
Follow this [digital ocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-20-04)

> If you see this error
>
> Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>
> See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
> details.

Open `sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

Un comment these

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
```

Open `sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

Un comment these

```
-Xms4g 
-Xmx4g
```

Open `sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

Update this

```
discovery.seed_hosts: []
```

At last run these

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

To check if its working or not run this command

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, java was missing from my server
When I have reconfigured my new server I did not check java.

After install java, it starts working.

It may help someone

Please first check java is pre-installed or not... because it is a pre-requirement of elasticsearch.

```
# systemctl status elasticsearch.service
# which java
# locate java
# java --version
# sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
# java --version
# sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch
# sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and in my case, the issue was with the installation part. I followed automatic installation steps in [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html).
After searching for a while, I tried the manual approach described in the same documentation, work like a magic for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some people this might be the case as it was for me so this might help someone.I am noob in writing such things so bear with me.

So got this error

> Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapException: org.elasticsearch.cli.UserException: unable to create temporary keystore a>

> Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore.tmp

> elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

> elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

for ubuntu 20.04,
workaround for this was to run these two commands:

`sudo chmod g+w /etc/elasticsearch`

Above command changes file permissions (allowing) for creating keystroke manually.And below command create that manually.

```
sudo -u elasticsearch -s /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore create
```

Answer (score 0):

**I also faced the same problem**

I checked the elasticsearch service status

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

Next, run the code below to determine the cause of the error:

```
journalctl -xe
```

I see a lots of line about Performance analyzer

```
Dec 20 21:07:37 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:07:37 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:07:37 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:07:37 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:07:42 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:07:42 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:07:42 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:07:42 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:07:42 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:07:42 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:07:47 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:07:47 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:07:47 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:07:47 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:07:47 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:07:47 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:07:52 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:07:52 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:07:52 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:07:52 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:07:52 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:07:52 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:07:57 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:07:57 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:07:57 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:07:57 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:07:57 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:07:57 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:08:02 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:08:02 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:08:02 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:08:02 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:08:02 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:08:02 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:08:07 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:08:07 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:08:07 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
Dec 20 21:08:07 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: Dec 20, 2019 9:08:07 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Dec 20 21:08:07 my performance-analyzer-agent-cli[13112]: INFO: Single batch             : No bind variables have been provided with a single statement batch execution. This may be due to accidental API misuse
```

This makes problem to analyze the issue
So First I tried to stop it so I found a link

in /usr/lib/systemd/system/opendistro-performance-analyzer.service

under [Service] add **StandardOutput=null**

after that reload systemd via **‘/bin/systemctl daemon-reload’** for it to take affect

For more Detail follow the below link
https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/performance-analyzer-agent-cli-spamming-syslog-in-od-1-3-0/2040/4

Now the picture was clear easily I found the issue that There were duplicate properties in the elasticsearch.yml file that I forgot to comment on. I commented out the duplicate property and restart the elasticsearch service.

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

**That's all.**

**I hope It will help.**

Answer (score 0):

I had to also disable security in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

`xpack.security.enabled: false`