# Error when I trying to start Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've installed ElasticSearch and I'm trying to start, before installing Magento. I'm getting this error:

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

systemctl status elasticsearch.service -l
    ● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-04-26 14:15:09 -03; 7s ago
         Docs: https://www.elastic.co
      Process: 3062 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Main PID: 3062 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
       CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
    
    Apr 26 14:15:08 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd-entrypoint[3062]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)Apr 26 14:15:08 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd-entrypoint[3062]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:75)
    Apr 26 14:15:08 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd-entrypoint[3062]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:116)Apr 26 14:15:08 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd-entrypoint[3062]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:79)
    Apr 26 14:15:08 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd-entrypoint[3062]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115)
    Apr 26 14:15:08 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd-entrypoint[3062]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:81)
    Apr 26 14:15:09 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Apr 26 14:15:09 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
    Apr 26 14:15:09 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
    Apr 26 14:15:09 vps-5443219.labarba.digital systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

I tried to follow this link to solve this problem: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656747/elasticsearch-job-for-elasticsearch-service-failed`

None of these solutions works for me.

Any help, please?

Ps1.: I'm using VPS Hostgator.
Ps2.: To install, I'm following this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved!

Just change in /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options:

OLD: `#-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}`

NEW: `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/log/elasticsearch`

For me, the problem is solved!