# Issue on Magento2 installation with elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, magento2

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.thecoachsmb.com/how-to-install-magento-2-on-ubuntu/) for Magento2 installation on an Ubuntu 21.04 VPS.
But when I get to the step to do the setup:install (see the code below) I get an error saying that no alive nodes could be found for Elasticsearch.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=<your-domain> --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=magento2 --db-password=<your-db-password-of-magento2-user> --admin-firstname=Admin --admin-lastname=Admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=<your-admin-password> --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --backend-frontname=admin --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

Before starting the process Elasticsearch is running correctly (see below output of `systemctl start elasticsearch.service`)

> elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled;
> vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-01-11 00:36:48 UTC; 13s ago
> Docs:
> Main PID: 625 (java)
> Tasks: 54 (limit: 2251)
> Memory: 1.2G
> CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
> |- 625 /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java -Xshare:auto
> -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encod>             `-1225 /usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller

But after running the above mentioned command, getting the error and checking again the status of elasticsearch I get the following:

> elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled;
> vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2022-01-11 00:39:44 UTC; 36s
> ago
> Docs:
> Process: 625 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint
> -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=killed, signal=KILL)                                                                         Main PID: 625 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
> Jan 11 00:35:39 server1..dmaker..mx systemd1: Starting
> Elasticsearch...
> Jan 11 00:36:48 server1..dmaker..mx systemd1: Started Elasticsearch.
> Jan 11 00:39:44 server1..dmaker..mx systemd1: elasticsearch.service:
> Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
> Jan 11 00:39:44 server1..dmaker..mx systemd1: elasticsearch.service:
> Failed with result 'signal'.
> Jan 11 00:39:44 server1..dmaker..mx systemd1: elasticsearch.service:
> Unit process 1225 (controller) remains running after unit stopped.

Trying to start the service again with `systemctl start elasticsearch.service` gives the following output:

> Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a fatal signal was
> delivered to the control process.
> See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
> details.

And `journalctl -xe` gives the following output:

> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [    975]   121   975
> 116649      334   131072        0             0 gsd-sharing
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1003]   121  1003
> 85475      486   147456        0             0 gsd-printer
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1037]   118  1037
> 61388      763   102400        0             0 colord
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1088]     0  1088
> 3757      373    65536        0             0 sshd
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1091]   121  1091
> 78788     1139   110592        0             0 ibus-daemon
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1096]   121  1096
> 59417      125    90112        0             0 ibus-dconf
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1099]   121  1099
> 225000     2525   405504        0             0 ibus-x11
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1105]   121  1105
> 59380      132    86016        0             0 ibus-portal
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1162]   121  1162
> 40960      127    77824        0             0 ibus-engine-sim
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1174]     0  1174
> 3370      245    61440        0             0 login
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1199]     0  1199
> 3844      366    69632        0             0 systemd
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1200]     0  1200
> 25543      838    94208        0             0 (sd-pam)
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1206]     0  1206
> 2826      358    53248        0             0 bash
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1250]     0  1250
> 2824      377    57344        0             0 bash
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1612]     0  1612
> 3756      371    69632        0             0 sshd
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1634]     0  1634
> 2824      374    57344        0             0 bash
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1642]     0  1642
> 3601      215    57344        0             0 sudo
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1643]     0  1643
> 3302       70    61440        0             0 systemctl
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1644]     0  1644
> 3279      146    61440        0             0 systemd-tty-ask
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1645]   123  1645
> 908357   296416  2744320        0             0 java
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: [   1835]   123  1835
> 22973      144    81920        0             0 controller
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel:
> oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/elasticsearch.service,task=java,pid=1645,uid=123
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: Out of memory: Killed
> process 1645 (java) total-vm:3633428kB, anon-rss:1185664kB,
> file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:123 pgtables:2680kB oom_score_adj:0
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process
> 1645 (java), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx systemd1: elasticsearch.service:
> Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
> -- Subject: Unit process exited                                                                                                                                                                                    -- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                                             -- Support:                                                                                                                                                                     --                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit elasticsearch.service has exited.
> --                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -- The process' exit code is 'killed' and its exit status is 9.                                                                                                                                                    Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx systemd1: elasticsearch.service:
> Failed with result 'signal'.
> -- Subject: Unit failed                                                                                                                                                                                            -- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                                             -- Support:                                                                                                                                                                       --                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -- The unit elasticsearch.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'signal'.
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx sudo[1642]: pam_unix(sudo:session):
> session closed for user root
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx systemd-entrypoint[1835]: 2022-01-11
> 00:57:21,546838 UTC [1835] INFO  Main.cc@111 Parent process died - ML
> controller exiting
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx systemd1: elasticsearch.service:
> Unit process 1835 (controller) remains running after unit stopped.
> Jan 11 00:57:21 server1-dmaker-mx systemd1: Failed to start
> Elasticsearch.
> -- Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has failed                                                                                                                                                  -- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                                             -- Support:                                                                                                                                                                          --                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -- A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has finished with a failure.
> --                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -- The job identifier is 1329 and the job result is failed.

From what I've investigated this may have something to do with the memory of my VPS. The elasticsearch process being killed due to lack of memory. But I need to be completely sure before thinking on upgrading my server, since my provider would charge me the monthly fee for the new upgraded plan.

My VPS has 2GB of RAM and 2 CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved

Firstly, Open /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml in your nano editor using the command below:

> sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

Your network settings should be:

- Set the bind-address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6): network.host: 127.0.0.1
- Set a custom port for HTTP: http.port: 9200

In order for Elasticsearch to allow connections from localhost, and to also listen on port 9200.

Next, run the code below to determine the cause of the error:

journalctl -xe

You can see the detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656748