# Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: magento2

> Platform: Magento 2 (V2.4.0) |
> Server: Linux Centos

When I run the command below,

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

I get the error,

> Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

When I run,

```
systemctl restart elasticsearch.service
```

I get the error,

> Failed to restart elasticsearch.service: Unit not found.

And when I run the command,

```
systemctl status elasticsearch
```

I get the error,

> Unit elasticsearch.service could not be found

However, I can see Elasticsearch folder and files in the following path:

> vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using these commands, i use them on my ubuntu instance

```
sudo -i service elasticsearch start
service elasticsearch restart
sudo -i service elasticsearch stop
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. got error "Failed to start elasticsearch.service: Unit not found."

Comment: It might be a storage issue try to increase your storage or check your Elasticsearch configs. Follow the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656747/elasticsearch-job-for-elasticsearch-service-failed

Comment: The problem seems to be that I haven't installed Elasticsearch. so when I installed it, it seems the issue has been resolved because is not throwing that error anymore. I will post more updates later here so others can know how to resolve this issue.